# Access Business Classes in WCF methods

Tags: wcf, class, asmx

I have an asmx web service I am converting to WCF. In the old structure I had a number of web service methods that accessed business classes to do the work. For example:

```
    public DataSet GetAppointmentDataToConvert(string aAccessToken, string aStartingId)
    {
        //verify that the user is allowed to use this web service
        if (!isAuthorized(aAccessToken))
        {
            throw new Exception("Not authorized");
        }

        cls256_BitEncryptionConversion cls256 = new cls256_BitEncryptionConversion();
        return cls256.GetAppointmentDataToConvert(aStartingId);


    }
```

This method initialized the cls256_BitEncryptionConversion class and called a method inside it to do the work, then returned the result.

I am trying to set up a WCF Service that will use the cls256_BitEncryptionConversion class, but despite both the class and the service being in the same namespace, my service method is unable to "see" the class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These are few tips for you to resolve it your self:

1. Make it sure that even they have the same namespace are they in the same project?
2. If they are in different project add it as you reference where you want to use it. And probably add a using directive if necessary.

Comment: They are in the same project and the same namespace. The business classes are all in an App_Code folder in the web project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by restructuring the project. I moved all the classes from the app_code folder into the root of the project.